# Can't delete files from a directory with ACL permissions

Tags: access-control-list

I'm getting stuck on acl for delete permissions.

My ssh default user is `ddn` and apache user `www-data`.

I set the following `setfacl` commands like this:

```
setfacl -m u:www-data:rwx,u:ddn:rwx shared/web/cache
setfacl -Rdm u:www-data:rwx,u:ddn:rwx shared/web/cache
```

But if I try to delete some files in this folder with the find command, I got denied permissions:

```
$ find shared/web/cache/ -type f -atime +70 -delete
find: cannot delete `shared/web/cache/e/f/7/d/7/ef7d7d26367b934f6965b6492b7183058669c80f.jpeg': Permission denied
find: cannot delete `shared/web/cache/f/e/7/f/0/fe7f09691670a1762c925d705135dc455752fb85.png': Permission denied
find: cannot delete `shared/web/cache/f/b/9/d/7/fb9d77e331ff45de1468ac584fa57e0c3aa6477a.png': Permission denied
find: cannot delete `shared/web/cache/f/1/e/f/9/f1ef953fde22f5d60f93dcc178130a894c2878f0.png': Permission denied
find: cannot delete `shared/web/cache/f/0/c/2/1/f0c21c21ae7f95d712dbe2c9255429022e33f31f.jpeg': Permission denied
find: cannot delete `shared/web/cache/2/f/8/f/7/2f8f78653021fffb99817b6a48c4d629a7de0aa6.png': Permission denied
find: cannot delete `shared/web/cache/2/f/9/d/7/2f9d7d22832a3517598bb61df2572869c30f7630.png': Permission denied
```

Same error with a simple rm command.

When I try to get acl info on one of those files:

```
$ getfacl shared/web/cache/e/f/7/d/7/ef7d7d26367b934f6965b6492b7183058669c80f.jpeg
# file: shared/web/cache/e/f/7/d/7/ef7d7d26367b934f6965b6492b7183058669c80f.jpeg
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rw-
user:www-data:rwx       #effective:rw-
user:ddn:rwx            #effective:rw-
group::r-x          #effective:r--
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

And the last folder:

```
$ getfacl shared/web/cache/e/f/7/d/7/
# file: shared/web/cache/e/f/7/d/7/
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx       #effective:r-x
user:ddn:rwx            #effective:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:user:ddn:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

I think I miss an important option on the setfacl command. Did you already got this issue? How to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: getfacl shared/web/cache/e/f/7/d/7/ef7d7d26367b934f6965b6492b7183058669c80f.jpeg

Comment: sorry i forgot getfacl shared/web/cache/e/f/7/d/7/

Comment: No problem @c4f4t0r, I updated the post. ;)

Comment: setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx,u:ddn:rwx shared/web/cache

Comment: It's works! But what is the difference? Thanks.

Comment: in the first command you missing -R option

Answer (score 3):

for setting the ACL permissions recurrently and effectivily in to the directory. you have to use below commands in the order.

```
setfacl -Rdm u:www-data:rwx,u:ddn:rwx shared/web/cache
```

(It will only for the future files)

```
setfacl -Rm u:www-data:rwx,u:ddn:rwx shared/web/cache
```

(Existing files and directories)